# How Programmatically can I Compute Path Length by Injecting numerical value to a node in an RDF Graph Using Jena Ontology API?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena

Building from the previous asked question ([How can I programmatically compute path length using Jena RDF/Ontology API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868524/how-can-i-programmatically-compute-path-length-using-jena-rdf-ontology-api?lq=1)), I need to multiply a numerical value (e.g. 3.5) to one of the specific class (its class size as detailed in the previous question) and be able to compute the overall path length(s) in an RDF Graph. Note that each path that fall-under this specific node will produce a new path weight result.

What I tried to do is to create a method called `nValue` and passed to it the `classSize` and the this numerical value variable then added it to the `pathSize` method for computing the `pathLength`, the method is as follows:

```java
public static double nValue (int classWeight, double nv )
{
  double numValue = classWeight*nv;
  if ( nv < 1 ){
    numValue = 1.0;
  }
  return numValue;
}
```

Then tried to call this method in the `pathSize` method to vain. My problem is that I'm new to Jena. So I have a problem in getting a single class in an RDF graph and perform the multiplications to it and combine it to the `pathLength` computation.

Comment: According to the FAQ, "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist".  The previous answers have given you a fair amount of code, and an answer to this question doesn't require all that much modification to the last answer.  So, what have you attempted (show us!), what didn't work (show us the bad results!), and what did you expect (mock up some fake, but good, results for us!)?

Comment: Please don't paste code in the comments;  the need to see your code is not mine alone.  Please edit your question to include the codes that you've written to attempt to solve this problem, to include the output that is generated, and to explain the results that you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the answer from the previous question was

```java
public static int classSize( final Resource klass ) {
    return klass.getModel().listSubjectsWithProperty( RDFS.subClassOf, klass ).toList().size();
}

public static double pathSize( final List<Resource> path ) {
    int prevSize = classSize( path.get( 0 )); 
    double pathSum = prevSize;
    for ( int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++ ) {
        int currSize = classSize( path.get( i ));
        double linkWeight = currSize < prevSize ? 0.5 : 1.0;
        pathSum += linkWeight + currSize;
        prevSize = currSize;
    }
    return pathSum;
}
```

It's not exactly clear to me what it is that you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're  trying to adjust the `currSize` in `pathSize` for certain classes (i.e., the value of returned by `path.get( i )`, but that you're having trouble comparing whether or not the class is one of the classes for which this should happen.  If I'm understanding correctly, you can do something like this:

```java
private static Resource specialClass = ResourceFactory.createResource( "http://.../specialClass" );

public static double pathSize( final List<Resource> path ) {
    // ...
    for ( int i = 1; i < path.size(); i++ ) {
        final Resource klass = path.get( i );
        int currSize = classSize( klass );
        if ( specialClass.equals( klass ) ) {      // When klass is specialClass
          currSize = ...; // something different   // do the additional modification
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Joshua thank you. Exactly, that's what I was trying to do and it has worked as I expected.